# FLUTTER CircleAvatar not displaying network image

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to display a network image of mario in a circleavatar using flutter. Nothing is displaying and no errors are returned. Please help! This is my code (Indents are screwed up):

```dart
CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://blogs.forbes.com/olliebarder/files/2018/03/super_mario_plumber_new.jpg") ,
        radius: 40.0,
),
```

It is part of a class which extends `StatelessWidget` and it is wrapped in a padding, and a column.

Comment: That works for me https://codepen.io/md-weber/pen/mdeMBbK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to hard-reset, use the green circle in vs code or android studio, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then `flutter run` in terminal.

Comment: doesn't work for me. is there some cache i need to clear?